# handlebars loop through inner object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an object of objects that looks like this:

```
Cards : [{ 
Object1 :['id':'3532']
Object2 :['id':'1456']
Object3 :['id':'1345']
}]
```

I am trying out handlebars.js I tried different template options none of which worked.

```
{{#Cards}}
{{#each this}}
    object name: {{this}} Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
{{/Cards}}
```

How can I output the below snippet in html, so that it loops through the entire Cards object and displays something like

```
<li>object name: object1: Key: id, value: 3532 </li>
<li>object name: object2: Key: id, value: 1456</li>
```

Comment: You'd have to write a helper function for handlebars

Comment: Your JSON data is kind of confusing. Is Cards really an Array with 1 value that is an Object with keys Object1, Object2, Object3 that have arrays as their values? You might be better off changing the format of this data if possible, it seems illogically formatted

Comment: @corydanielson Cards is an object with multiple objects, each object has an array with many fields in it, i just narrowed it down for the example.

Comment: the array is created in php  it is then json encoded sent over to javascript which runs json.parse on it, this is the result. If i use original data without parsing I cannot template it out.

Comment: Oh, ok. This isn't properly formatted JSON, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/r7unb/

From the comments, I think your data is structured like this:

```
var data = {
    Cards: {
        Object1: ['id','3532'],
        Object2: ['id','1456'],
        Object3: ['id','1345']
    }
};
```

Given that set of data, you'd need to register a helper in order to print the items of the array at will. (I didn't find such a method on Handlebars docs). That helper would look something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('printIndex', function printIndex(index, arr) {
    index = parseInt(index);

    if ( index >= 0 && arr.length > index ) {
        var r = arr[index];
    } else {
        throw new Error("printIndex helper: Array out of bounds. printIndex received " + index + ", array length is " + arr.length);
    }

    return r;
});
```

Now with that helper, you could print the data using the following template:

```
<ul>
{{#each Cards}}
    <li>object name: {{@key}} Key: {{printIndex 0 this}} Value = {{printIndex 1 this}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: awesome job this looks great i shall go learn about the registerhelper method seems pretty useful

Comment: on the key i'm getting:  `Key: [object Object]` how would I go a level deeper would I change the helper or add another each loop in my template?

Comment: HM. Maybe tweak the helper to print differently if the value is an object. Can you console.log your dataset and update your question?